# XBRL Amount of names for a business fact

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex, xbrl

How can we know beforehand the number of names that can a business fact in XBRL receive on  XBRL instance documents?

For example if we want to find the Revenue of companies by looking into XBRL instances for this business fact alone we can meet different names for this same fact as:

- us-gaap:Revenues
- us-gaap:SalesRevenue
- us-gaap:SalesRevenueNet

The target is to find out a finite amount of names that every business fact can receive and then for every business fact loop all these names until we fine the one that is in the instance document.

is there a lexicon if you will where it has all of these names into one file? This is a theoretical question but requires technical expertise.

And most importantly since there are many lookalike names for a business fact can a name in one XBRL instance mean one fact and on the other instance document mean another business fact?

**EDIT**

Do you believe this is [the place](http://xbrl.fasb.org/us-gaap/2013/) where all the namings exist. If it is why are they stored in `xml`? There should be element names and nothing more...

Comment: Are you just looking for the published taxonomies? http://www.xbrl.org/TaxonomyRecognition/US%20GAAP%202009/XBRLUS-USGAAP-Taxonomy-2008-10-31.htm

Comment: Well i have found the word taxonomies in XBRL numerous times but i havent found were the elements are so i can have their naming. I' ve been to this link before many times

Comment: @wst i have found many times this link http://xbrl.fasb.org/us-gaap/2013/ but i cannot understand why it has these items in `xml` instead of having them in a format that can be read...

Comment: They are in `xml` there is not a readable list. I cannot understand how for example for revenue can you find the entire number of names that can be used. Can you please provide a small example for any item? I have tried to understand it for the almost all the day

Comment: XML is readable, though there are many documents that make up that taxonomy. You would need to traverse them all to learn all possible element names.

Comment: Understood but are you sure these are the element names?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The elements are defined in a schema (an xsd file), which is itself an XML. This is nicely readable, why would you want a _readable list_? I have no knowledge about XBRL, but looking at schema files like http://xbrl.fasb.org/us-gaap/2013/elts/us-gaap-2013-01-31.xsd it seems quite clear definition of all the elements. So, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @MrIcyBalls ... Are you, in the end, asking why there is more than one fact named "Revenue"? Are you asking why there are so many elements that use the term "Revenue"? Are you, for instance, asking why there are separate "Revenue" and "Sales Revenue" elements?

Comment: @JeffFerguson yes. I am very curious about it because it is very tricky to find revenues e.g. by using XPath because the same economic fact has so many names like Revenue or Sales Revenue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements are different because they refer to different things. The `SalesRevenueNet` element is defined as follows:

> Total revenue from sale of goods and services rendered during the
>   reporting period, in the normal course of business, reduced by sales
>   returns and allowances, and sales discounts.

The `Revenues` element is defined as follows:

> Amount of revenue recognized from goods sold, services rendered,
>   insurance premiums, or other activities that constitute an earning
>   process. Includes, but is not limited to, investment and interest
>   income before deduction of interest expense when recognized as a
>   component of revenue, and sales and trading gain (loss).

(I can't find an element in the US GAAP taxonomy named `SalesRevenue`, so I can't comment on that one.)

The `SalesRevenueNet` element is a value summed from other elements, including `Sales Revenue, Goods, Net`, `Shipping and Handling Revenue`, `Sales Revenue, Shipping, Net`, and several other elements. The `SalesRevenueNet` element is, in turn, an item in the summation of the `Revenues` element, which also includes elements such as `Financial Services Revenue`. In algebraic terms, it looks like this:

```
SalesRevenueNet = SalesRevenueGoodsNet + ShippingAndHandlingRevenue + ...
Revenue = SalesRevenueNet + FinancialServicesRevenue
```

The [XBRL Taxonomy Viewer](http://viewer.xbrl.us/yeti2/resources/yeti-gwt/Yeti.jsp) might provide a better view into some of these relationships. Go the Taxonomy Viewer and do the following:

1. Select the "All Taxonomies" item in the "2013 US GAAP Taxonomy" section from the "Open Taxonomy" dialog that pops up when you bring up the site.
2. At the bottom of the page, in the "Search" tab of the "Tools" section, type in the name of an element (such as `SalesRevenueNet`) and click the "Search" button.
3. Click on the element name in the Search Results list. After a bit of time, the pane in the upper right will refresh with information about the element you selected, such as labels, references, and calculation information.